# «Несмотря на» — пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги

Несмотря на предстоящий праздник работник до последнего часа включительно должен соблюдать дисциплину, установленную на работе.

Answer (score 3):

***Несмотря на предстоящий праздник, работник... должен...***

Следует поставить запятую. Это подтверждается правилами и закономерностями использования оборотов с ***несмотря на***. Постановке запятой способствует и интонация: без паузы предложение не читается.

[**НЕСМОТРЯ НА (что)**, предлог](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_482)

> Обороты, присоединяемые предлогом «несмотря на», обычно обособляются (за исключением тех случаев, когда оборот входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу).
>
> ***Несмотря на** солнечное, теплое утро, он был в шубе и, видимо, грелся на солнце.* Д. Мамин-Сибиряк, Волшебник.