# Нужна ли запятая перед "несмотря на"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, предлоги

*Как быть, если ваш сотрудник(,) несмотря на предпринятые меры оказался недобросовестным работником.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Следует выделить запятыми весь оборот с ***несмотря на***:

*Как быть, если ваш сотрудник, **несмотря на предпринятые меры,** оказался недобросовестным работником.*

[**НЕСМОТРЯ НА (что)**, *предлог*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_482)

> Обороты, присоединяемые предлогом «несмотря на», обычно обособляются (за исключением тех случаев, когда оборот входит в состав сказуемого или тесно связан с ним по смыслу).

Данный оборот располагается между подлежащим и сказуемым, что тоже способствует его выделению. См. [**ПУНКТУАЦИЯ ПРИ ОБОРОТАХ С НЕПЕРВООБРАЗНЫМИ ПРЕДЛОГАМИ**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach1)

P. S. Посмотрите [ответ](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/462419/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/462420#462420) на Ваш прошлый вопрос.